# Using JavaScript to Show/Hide multiple fields on the same form with same id name

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm, crm, show-hide

I have to fields on the same Dynamics CRM form. One is Account Name and the other field is Company. They both share the same field id name which is parentcustomerid. I need to show/hide these fields based on the value of an option set of another field. I can get the Account name field to show/hide but the Company field will not show/hide.

> function showHideSourceField() {
>
> ```
> var type = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_type").getValue();
> var source = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_source");
> var accountname = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("parentcustomerid");
> var company = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("parentcustomerid");
>
> //Type of Contact is Unaffiliated
> if (type == 100000004) {
>
>     source.setVisible(true);
>     accountname.setVisible(false);
>     company.setVisible(false);
> ```

Comment: You can't reuse the same `id` in HTML elements

Comment: Is the name or class name different?

Comment: Please show us what you have done. also it's a bad practice assigning more than one element same Id, use class instead

Comment: Show us the HTML code.

Comment: Am I missing something? He isn't creating the html. If anyone is guilty of creating two elements with the same id it's Microsoft, and there's really nothing he can do about that particular issue.

Comment: Actually, it's not entirely clear from the question that this is about a CRM form and not a straight-forward html form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1) They are two different fields, and you can simply check this in the form editor, for example one is `name` the other is `parentcustomerid`

2) They are the same field added twice to the form, this is possible inside Dynamics CRM, in this case the first field is `parentcustomerid` an the second is `parentcustomerid1`, and you can still check if it is the same field inside the form editor.

Answer (score -1):

You mean same `name` attribute?

In Html you use:

- `id` to provide a unique identifier.
- `class` to provide a group/type/etc

I think the best solution for this is to provide a distinct name for each and use the same class for both.

```
<input id="account-name" class="parentcustomer" name="account" />
<input id="company" class="parentcustomer" name="company" />
```

Then you can:

```
$('.parentcustomer').hide();
$('.parentcustomer').show();
```

Comment: In dynamics CRM you should not access the DOM in this way (it's possible in a pinch, but could break with future releases). The framework provides a method to access elements on the page without css selectors.

Comment: The original question code was changed. He didn't provide any info about CRM he was using. That why this answer may not be the right with this new info. Should I delete?